# My computer just switches on and off, over and over. What's wrong with it?

Tags: windows-10, partitioning

I partitioned my hard drive to install Ubuntu (22.04.2 LTS) alongside Windows 10. During the ubuntu installation I got the error 'Unable to install Ubuntu. This is a fatal error'. I tried installing a different version, it still didn't work. Whenever I switch on the computer now, it switches on and doesn't display anything, and switches back off. It switches back on and this continues the whole time. During the Ubuntu installation, I didn't interfere with the partition with Windows 10 installed. Could it be possible that my Windows 10 partition was somehow erased?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: *it switches on and doesn't display anything, and switches back off* - this behaviour is unlikely to do with anything you've done, seems like a hardware fault has developed - do you have any debug LED's on your motherboard to determine at what point the POST is failing? do you have a speaker you can attach to the appropriate pins on the motherbaord so you can hear any so called "beep codes" that can also indicate what is failing

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to determine if there's a hardware issue: Use a tested Ubuntu Live USB (perhaps the one you used) to **boot from USB**, without installing. If that works, there is no hardware issue, other than possibly the HDD/SSD.

- If you cannot boot from a USB device that *has been tested on another PC*, then likely there is a hardware issue. Get professional repairs.
- If the machine boots from USB, the best bet is to *restore the drive from the last full disk image* made before attempting Ubuntu installation.
- If you failed to make a disk image, you may need to restore Windows from the manufacturer's recovery/rescue disk. Since this will likely destroy all data, *first make a disk image*, e.g., using software such as [AOMEI Backup](https://www.aomeitech.com/) or [Macrium Reflect](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree) on a rescue USB.
- Finally, if all else fails, the disk can be wiped (if not defective) and a new OS installed.